# Taylor expanding implicit curves

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> $$ x \cos y + y \cos x = 0$$

Suppose I wished to write the above as polynomial around $x=0$, we can see by substitution of $x=0$ that $y=\pi$ around that point from the original equation. Hence, could we write the equation as:

$$ x \left[ \pi  +\frac{d y}{dx} \frac{ (y- \pi)^2}{2!} .. + stuff \right] + y \left[ 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} .. stuff \right]=0 $$

Is the above equation correct? What would be the rationale/ intuition behind expanding $y$ individually in the equation?

Comment: Where are you getting $[0,\pi)$? That point does *not* satisfy your equation!

Comment: Typo. $(0,\pi)$.

Comment: Oof good catch, think it's fixed now @TedShifrin

Answer (score 1):

If we limit to first order, it means that you want to approximate the function
$$f(x,y)=x \cos (y) + y \cos( x)$$ by a plane. It would then be something like
$$f(x,y)= a + b x$$ with
$$a=a_0+a_1(y-\pi) \qquad \text{and} \qquad b=b_0+b_1(y-\pi)$$ I am sure that you can make the link between coefficients $(a_0,a_1,b_0,b_1)$ and the partial derivatives of $f(x,y)$ at $(0,\pi)$.

Comment: Hmm , how did you go from the $ f(x,y) = x \cos (y) + y \cos(x)$ to $ f(x,y) = a+bx$ , did you expand it by multivariable taylor series? This is an idea but my original question was about expanding individual terms in an equation

Comment: @Buraian. Forget, for the time being, your specific problem. Suppose that, for given $x$, $z$ is linear wrt $y$ and vice-versa. So, you have $z=(a_0+a_1x)+(b_0+b_1) y$ which translates both behaviors. Is it better ? Do you see the connection ?

Comment: Hmm,  $ z(x,y) = z(0,0)+ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} a_1 + \frac{ \partial z}{ \partial y} y$ looks like taylor series only

Comment: @Buraian. This is exactly the point. Now, the question is : what about the cross term ?

Comment: I think so it should be the second order partials: $\frac{1}{2!} \left[ \frac{ \partial z}{\partial y \partial x}   \right]$   I am a bit worried if I should consider order of partials because the the derivatives are not commutative

Answer (score 0):

$y(0)=\pi$,then D.w.r.t. $x$ would lead to
$$x\cos y+y \cos x=0 \implies \cos y -xy'\sin y+y'\cos x-y\sin x 
\implies y'(0)=0$$
Similarly, go on D. w.t. $x$ to get $y''(0)$, $y'''(0)$ etc.
Then the series will be $$y(x)=\pi-x+y''(0)\frac{x^2}{2!}+y'''(0)\frac{x^3}{3!}+...$$